# read local csv file in pySpark (2.3)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-sql

I'm using pySpark 2.3, trying to read a csv file that looks like that:

```
0,0.000476517230863068,0.0008178378961061477
1,0.0008506156837329876,0.0008467260987257776
```

But it doesn't work:

```
from pyspark import sql, SparkConf, SparkContext
print (sc.applicationId)
>> <property at 0x7f47583a5548>
data_rdd = spark.textFile(name=tsv_data_path).filter(x.split(",")[0] != 1)
```

And I get an error:

```
AttributeError: 'SparkSession' object has no attribute 'textFile'
```

Any idea how I should read it in pySpark 2.3?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, `textFile` exists on the `SparkContext` (called `sc` in the repl), not on the `SparkSession` object (called `spark` in the repl).

Second, for CSV data, I would recommend using the CSV `DataFrame` loading code, like this:

```
df = spark.read.format("csv").load("file:///path/to/file.csv")
```

You mentioned in comments needing the data as an RDD.  You are going to have significantly better performance if you can keep all of your operations on DataFrames instead of RDDs.  However, if you need to fall back to RDDs for some reason you can do it like the following:

```
rdd = df.rdd.map(lambda row: row.asDict())
```

Doing this approach is better than trying to load it with `textFile` and parsing the CSV data yourself.  If you use the `DataFrame` CSV loading then it will properly handle all the CSV edge cases for you like quoted fields.  Also if only needed some of the columns, you could filter on the `DataFrame` before converting it to a `RDD` to avoid needing to bring all that extra data over into the python interpreter.

Comment: But this will produce Dataframe right? I need the RDD

Comment: Why do you specifically need an RDD?  DataFrames will give you much better performance if you are using python.  I'll update the example with how to convert to an RDD if you really want to do that.

Comment: try `DataFrame.rdd`